# How to add multiple 3d objects to one modelviewer

Tags: javascript, model-viewer

how to add multiple 3d objects in a modelviewer.
I tried this https://github.com/google/model-viewer/issues/482#issuecomment-551268896
but it didn't work.

code

```html
<model-viewer>
<model-node src="a.glb"></model-node>
<model-node src="b.glb"></model-node>

</model-viewer>
```

Comment: show us what you have tried and explain what didn't work

Comment: uh so i updated the question to show the code.

Comment: the thing that doesnt work is i cant see anything

Comment: i mean no output

Comment: and why didn't it work? any error messages? did it show only one model not the other, can you display the models separately not together

Comment: no models were visibl and no errors

Comment: and it works when displayed in two `<model-viewers>` but i want both of them to work in model node

Comment: Where are the .glb files located?

Comment: inside the projetc folder

Comment: Looking through the project, that link is a proposed improvement to the model viewer, i can't find anything to say that it has been implemented, so that may be your issue

Answer (score 0):

The feature of adding multiple model nodes into a single `<model-viewer>` was only conceptualized, and has not been implemented.

As stated by the Github post that you linked to:

> This *suggests* a declarative API for incorporating multiple models into a single  element (emphasis mine)...

The conversation in this Github issue goes on to describe multiple implementation suggestions if they were to incorporate the feature.

If you're looking to create a scene with multiple models, you're going to need to use a library such as [three.js](https://threejs.org/) until they've ironed out the details of this proposed feature.

If you use ReactJS, you can use [gltfjsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gltfjsx), which significantly simplifies the process of importing a model with multiple mesh nodes. It builds a component for you using react-three/drei, and separates out each mesh node in the component for you.

Here's an example of a component generated with gltfjsx:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGLTF } from '@react-three/drei'

export default function Model(props) {
  const group = useRef()
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/example-3d.glb')
  return (
    <group ref={group} {...props} dispose={null}>
      <group scale={56.66}>
        <mesh geometry={nodes.Curve001_1.geometry} material={materials.Material} />
        <mesh geometry={nodes.Curve001_2.geometry} material={materials['Material.002']} />
      </group>
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('/example-3d.glb')
```

This component can now be used anywhere to include your 3d model.

Comment: oh isnt there something simpler

Comment: @Jotham Not really. You could try a CMS like [sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/blogs/enterprise/news/getting-started-with-sketchfab) that helps streamline the process of embedding 3d models. However, I'm not sure if that will include the functionality you're looking for.